# datatables custom filtering

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am pretty surprised at how custom filtering works in datatables.
It seems like i need to define a **global** filter function like this:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) { .. });
```

and then **ALL** datatables on my page will use that function to filter. This is not acceptable.

What i need is a way to programmatically filter a datatable using a custom filter function. I would expect this function to take a row and return true/false based on some criteria to show/hide that row from the result.

does a way of doing this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this link help:

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8435/remove-custom-filtering/p1

```
/* Custom filtering function which will filter data in column four between two values */
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
            if ( oSettings.nTable.id === "my_filtering_table" ) {
                var selectCode = document.getElementById('statusSelect').value;
                return filterRow(selectCode, aData);
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: actually my solution ended up being very similar. I am both happy and sad that the author endorses this hack.