# Datatables multiple or filter in select

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

Hello I would like to filter my items in my datatable by select input.
But when I filter it, datatables uses AND method. I would like to filter my items with OR.

The point is when I choose HOME and WORK filter in select input it must display me items from HOME or WORK category (not items which are in home and work category both like is now).

The HTML Code:

```
    <h4>Select your multiple filter</h4>
<div>
    <select id="select-category" name="categories" multiple>
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="Home">Home</option>
        <option value="Work">Work</option>
        <option value="City">City</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <h4>Table of items</h4>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>Lamp</td><td>Home</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Desk</td><td>Work</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2</td><td>Books</td><td>Home</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Cars</td><td>City</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Desk</td><td>Work</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Photocopying</td><td>Work</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Clip</td><td>Work</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Street</td><td>City</td></tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The JS Code:

```
var dataTable = $('table').dataTable();
$('#select-category').change( function () { 
    dataTable.fnFilter( $('#select-category').val(),2);
});
```

Here is my jsfiddle link with my example of filtering with AND, which i want to change to OR.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6uQ2/13/

Comment: Regex? [http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/12941/logical-or-filter-for-one-specific-column](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/12941/logical-or-filter-for-one-specific-column)

Comment: It looks like it's a total headache to get the solution to datatables in this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199759/datatables-custom-filtering I've gotten to the point of filtering but now trying to get the filteredData back in is proving unsuccessful, also there would be issue with then reverting back to a `non-filtered` version. http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/Z6uQ2/15/

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I tried regex, and this works.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6uQ2/17/

Comment: I Change link for - http://jsfiddle.net/Z6uQ2/20/ - you must disable smart search by passing `code`dataTable.fnFilter(choosedString,2,true,false);`/code`