# How to use Select box outside to filter dataTables?

Tags: jquery, search, drop-down-menu, datatables, filtering

I'm using the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) Table plug-in for jQuery but I'm having trouble 
getting the global input search box would be an select box.

With the [sDOM](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#sDom) option `lrtip`, filtering input is not show but is 
it possible to display select box and getting the datatable to filter based on the change of the select box?

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#table_page').DataTable( {
        paging:   true,
        ordering: false,        
        info:     true,
        searching: true, 
        sDom: "lrtip" // default is lfrtip, where the f is the filter
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="table_page" class="display cell-border" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you seen [Individual column searching (select inputs) example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)?

Comment: Yes, but I want global searching not  Individual column searching.

Comment: Looks like your answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199759/datatables-custom-filtering

Comment: No, it's a solution to programmatically filter a datatable using a custom filter function not to use select box as global search.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) API method to perform global search programmatically and [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option to disable built-in search control.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   dom: 'lrtip'
});

$('#table-filter').on('change', function(){
   table.search(this.value).draw();   
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/zmoos6tu/1/) for code and demonstration. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/zmoos6tu/3/), if you want to replace default search box.

Comment: OK, but do you think is it possible to have select box in the same row as "Show entries" (like the input search box with sDom 'lfrtip' option)

Comment: @ Gyrocode.com Wow !  
update your answer so I accept it. Thanks for your help, cheers.

Comment: @LeMoussel, updated the answer. Also there was a typo in the last example which is corrected, see https://jsfiddle.net/zmoos6tu/3

Answer (score 1):

There are two to search a string using your custom field as I created custom field Month's outside the DataTable scope and used below code to make it workable like search box.

1.First solution, once you click on drop down search box will filled with what you selected and populate the result but you can always see search box with selected value.

HTML:

```
<select name="month-select" id="month-select" class="monthlist" onclick="">
                <option value="">Month's</option>
                <option value="<?php echo date('Y');?>-01">Jan</option>
                <option value="<?php echo date('Y');?>-02">Feb</option>
                <option value="<?php echo date('Y');?>-03">Mar</option>
                <option value="<?php echo date('Y');?>-04">Apr</option>
                <option value="<?php echo date('Y');?>-05">May</option>
                <option value="<?php echo date('Y');?>-06">Jun</option>
                <option value="<?php echo date('Y');?>-07">Jul</option>
                <option value="<?php echo date('Y');?>-08">Aug</option>
                <option value="<?php echo date('Y');?>-09">Sep</option>
                <option value="<?php echo date('Y');?>-10">Oct</option>
                <option value="<?php echo date('Y');?>-11">Nov</option>
                <option value="<?php echo date('Y');?>-12">Dec</option>
                </select>
```

Javascript Code :

```
var selectedValue=$("#month-select").val();    
table.search(selectedValue).draw();
```

2. Second solution I like as it is not showing anything in datatable master search field and result comes without modifying search field

   ```
   var selectedValue=$("#month-select").val();
    table.columns(6).search( selectedValue ).draw();
   ```

**columns(6)** you can modified this number 6 as per your column order.