# How to extend data by using Select Box outside of Datatables?

Tags: jquery, filter, drop-down-menu, datatables

There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263248/how-to-use-select-box-outside-to-filter-datatables) to Filter data in Datatable which is filter whole amount of data. Thus you have 100 rows, f.e. and putting some options choose just few of them - 20-30 from 100. Here is code: `https://jsfiddle.net/zmoos6tu/1/` and here is explanation `https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/48079/search-filter-dropdowns`.

I need other solution for my project. Let's imagine that I have 1000000 rows in DB however by default I show only 100 rows as active rows. But when user choose full rows option in select I want all the DB will load instead of only active rows.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

For that jsfiddle example I want to show only London rows by default and not load others at all (!) and **only if user choose All - than request server for additional data.**